How to change a certain color in vim?
When I open the terminal, go to preferences and then to colors, I can change most colors, but there's one that I can't seem to change.
Here's what it looks like in a java file:

The only time I see this color is when I'm editing a file in Java, C, or C++ (I'm sure it shows up for files in other languages, too). All keywords related to classes, objects, or variables show up in this color (see the image linked above).
Is there any way I can find out where the value for this color is stored and change it? If it matters, I use vim.

If you're using a text editor; the color change you need to make is within that text editor; ie. change to a different vim color theme, or modify your existing theme to make it what you want.

... more specifically, it depends on the editor's syntax highlighting files for the particular language. For the default vim package on Ubuntu 22.04 that's likely a combination of /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim and (for Java) /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/java.vim. See also vim - How do I tell what syntax file is being used?

Surely the title should be "How to change a certain color in vim?"

How tokens are highlighted in vim depends on vim's effective color scheme and on the current language.
There are many degrees to which the effective color scheme for the current language may be altered; I'm going to describe how to make small adjustments to the effective color scheme for a specific language and for the default theme, for a single user, as that's probably the most common scenario.
First off, you need to determine which syntax group the token you want to change belongs to; open a file in your target language using vim, place the cursor on any character of the token (in this case, e.g., on either p / u / b / ... in public) and run:
:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1)), 'name')

This will output the syntax group's name of the current token (in this case: Type).
You'll also need to figure out the filetype of your target language:
:set filetype?

This will output the current filetype of the current file (in this case: java).
Next, you'll need to tell vim to highlight the Type syntax group in java files using a different color.
First, create a directory to store overrides to syntax rules:
mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/syntax

Pick a 256-color-terminal-compatible color, then create a file named the same as the filetype + .vim (in this case, java.vim):
vim ~/.vim/after/syntax/java.vim

Finally, add this line to the file, replacing 196 with the color you picked:
highlight Type ctermfg=196

This is the outcome when overriding subs' names in Perl (note how the foo token changes from cyan to red); before:

after:


I'm having some difficulty with this. I was trying to change the color for the syntax group I mentioned before, but for c instead of java (I haven't tried java yet). Using the command you listed, it said the name of the syntax group is "Type". But, when I put "highlight Type ctermfg=Red", for example, the Type color doesn't change in my files. Also, it only lets me use certain colors for this syntax group (if I tried to set it equal to "#FFFFFF" for example instead of something like "Red" or "Blue" it will throw an error). Is there any way to set this syntax group to a certain hex color?

@stackoverflowuser I apologize, I got confused with guifg. You need to specify a 256 color terminal-compatible color with ctermfg (I'll amend my answer). That is probably plenty already, however if you wan to use HTML colors, you can use guifg and put set termguicolors in ~/.vimrc

@stackoverflowuser ... along with syntax on
